# 3-dimensional hyperbolic space

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

In the 3-dimensional hyperbolic space there are given a plane $\mathcal{P}$ and four distinct lines $a_1, a_2, r_1, r_2$ in such positions that $a_1$ and $a_2$ are perpendicular to $\mathcal{P}$, $r_1$ is coplanar with $a_1, r_2$ is coplanar with $a_2$, finally $r_1$ and $r_2$ intersect $\mathcal{P}$ at the same angle. Rotate $r_1$ around $a_1$ and rotate $r_2$ around $a_2$; denote by $\mathcal{S}_1$ and $\mathcal{S}_2$ the two surfaces of revolution they sweep out. Show that the common points of $\mathcal{S}_1$ and $\mathcal{S}_2$ lie in a plane.

Comment: Where does the question arise from?

Comment: It's KöMaL A.538.

Comment: Here is a link to the problem: https://www.komal.hu/feladat?a=feladat&f=A538&l=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $L$ be the geodesic segment in $P$ with one endpoint at $a_1 \cap P$ and the other endpoint at $a_2 \cap P$.  Let $b$ be the midpoint of $L$.  We define a plane $Q$ by requiring it to contain $b$ and by requiring it to be perpendicular to $L$ (and thus to $P$). Thus  reflection in $Q$ exchanges $a_1$ and $a_2$.  It is now an exercise to prove that reflection in $Q$ exchanges the “cones” $S_1$ and $S_2$. Thus $S_1 \cap S_2$ lies in the plane $Q$.

---

Here I am assuming that the lines $r_1$ and $r_2$ actually meet $P$ — the question is slightly unclear on this detail.

Comment: If the reflection in $Q$ exchanges  $a_1$ and  $a_2$, $Q$ is the perpendicular bisection plane of the common perpendicular to $a_1$ and $a_2$. But if so, the $S_1$ is not sure to be the reflection of $S_2$ to $Q$. Because $r_1$ is not sure to be the reflection of $r_2$.

Comment: Maybe there's something I misunderstand?

Comment: You are correct that $r_1$ and $r_2$ need not be reflections of each other.  But some rotation of $r_2$ is a reflection of $r_1$, because of the angle condition.  And that suffices.

Comment: I still don't really understand the definition of $Q$. Could you please describe it again?

Comment: Because... Anyway, $S_1$ isn't the reflection of $S_2$. Therefore the intersections of them won't lie in $Q$.

Comment: I've revised the wording to make the definition of $Q$ more clear and correct. Hope this helps you.

Comment: yeah, I think I have understood it. By the way, is the proof the same in the euclidean case? Because the $a_1\cap r_1$ isn't the reflection of $a_2\cap r_2$, the intersection won't be on the "perpendicular bisection plane" $Q$. (Maybe it will be a little left or right to the central?)

Comment: It is, the "determine the position (or distance) by angle" is right only in hyperbolic or spherical cases.

Comment: Good catch - the proof does not work in the euclidean case.  I've removed that line of the answer.  The proof _does_ work in the spherical case... I think.